# Is there a 'START AT' equivalent in MS-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Some databases support commands such as:

```
SELECT TOP 10 START AT 10 * FROM <TABLE>
```

Essentially I need to pull the first 10 records, then the next 10, then the next 10 etc.  Maybe there is another way to do this but in the past I've done it like the above for databases that support 'START AT'.

Comment: I'm curious, what databases other than Sybase SQL Anywhere support the `START AT` clause?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which version of SQL Server?

In SQL Server 2000 this is a real pain (though possible using ugly tricks like that posted by stingyjack).

In 2005 and later it's a little easier- look at the [Row_Number()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function.

And, depending on your client application it may not even be that hard.  Some of the ASP.Net grid controls have support for automatic paging.

Answer (score 9):

For [SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx)

```
SELECT * 
FROM <TABLE>
ORDER BY <SomeCol>
OFFSET 10 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: Nice to see that SQL Server finally adds some sort of specifying an `OFFSET`! This syntax seems compatible with DB2, Derby and Ingres...

Comment: @LukasEder - It's SQL:2008 standard [AFAIK](http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/#select-limit-offset)

Comment: Hmm, the [last SQL:2008 draft that I have seen](http://www.wiscorp.com/sql200n.zip) doesn't mention such an extension to the `<order by clause>` (page 837 in 5CD2-02-Foundation-2006-01.pdf). But that's just a draft, so maybe in the final SQL:2008 standard document, they may have actually added that clause...?comments may only be edited for 5 minutes(click on this box to dismiss)

Comment: @LukasEder - Don't know. I was just going off what [my previous link](http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/#select-limit-offset) says. I don't have access to a copy either.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT Top 10 * 
FROM Table 
WHERE <primary key> Not IN (
    SELECT Top 10 <primaryKey> 
    FROM Table 
    ORDER BY <primary Key> ASC) 
ORDER BY <primary Key> ASC
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to be compatible with SQL Server 2000 you could use

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 10 FROM
    (
        SELECT TOP (n * 10) FROM <table> ORDER BY (column) ASC
    ) AS t1 ORDER BY (column) DESC
) AS t2 ORDER BY (column) ASC
```

In SQL Server 2005 there is a new function Row_Number(). You could use it this way:

```
WITH Orders AS 
(
     SELECT SalesOrderID, OrderDate, 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by OrderDate) AS 'RowNumber' 
     FROM SalesOrder
) 
SELECT * 
FROM Orders 
WHERE RowNumber between 10 and 19;
```