# Grails generates questionable pagination queries for MSSQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, grails, pagination, grails-orm

I'm using Grails 1.3.7 and MSSQL Server 2008.
Doing simple query through both dynamic finders or criteria like this:

```
Invoice.findAllByClient(client, [max: 25, offset: 100000, sort: 'title'])
```

or

```
Invoice.createCriteria().list(max: 25, offset: 100000) {
    eq('client', client)
    order('title')
}
```

and watching the actual query that is thrown to the MSSQL Server:

select top 100000 etc

The query is obviously inefficient. Is that a bitter truth with Grails that cannot generate an efficient query for MSSQL or I'm missing something?

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not that Grails (or rather [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/), the underlying database technology) cannot generate somewhat more efficient queries. It doesn't due to the limitations of SQL Server 2000, which does not support more efficient generic syntax for paginating queries (see [e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447623/what-is-a-good-way-to-paginate-out-of-sql-2000-using-start-and-length-parameters)).

If you don't specify a [dialect](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/dialect/Dialect.html) for your data source, Hibernate will default to using the base [SQLServerDialect](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/dialect/SQLServerDialect.html), which [generates the inefficient queries you are seeing](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/SQLServerDialect.java#L89). Switching to the [SQLServer2008Dialect](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/dialect/SQLServer2008Dialect.html) in your data source should [generate somewhat more efficient queries using common table expressions](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/SQLServer2005Dialect.java#L77), e.g. (taken from the Javadoc),

```
WITH query AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY orderby) as __hibernate_row_nr__,
    original_query_without_orderby
)
SELECT * FROM query WHERE __hibernate_row_nr__ BETWEEN offset AND offset + last
```

To do this in Grails, simply set the `dialect` property in `conf/Datasource.groovy` as [documented here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.3%20The%20DataSource), e.g.

```
dataSource {
   // configuration you already have
   dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It makes perfect sense. However, SQLServer2008Dialect class is not present in the hibernate bundle included in Grails 1.3.7. I suppose an upgrade to latest hibernate must be done. Am I right?

Comment: @Andrey.Kozyrev: You know, I neglected to check the available dialects bundled with Grails. Unfortunately, I strongly suspect that upgrading the version of Hibernate might break GORM. I think you're best bet would be to create a custom dialect class that copies the implementation [of the latest version of the dialect](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-core/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/SQLServer2005Dialect.java) or, alternatively, migrate to Grails 2.0, which uses Hibernate 3.5.